# Sorting API response with python to excel or csv. Python

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, request

I'm trying to sort out  UK Police free API response to a readable format-csv or excel. 
Im using Requests library. My initial code is getting the response in a json format:

```
import requests

r=requests.get('https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=51.169,-0.633:51.186,-0.5436:51.226,-0.6224&date=2019-12')
r_json=r.json()
for i in j:
    for key,value in i.items():
        print (key, ":", value)
```

**The code above produces as follows:**

```
category : anti-social-behaviour location_type : Force location : {'latitude': '51.196818', 'street': {'id': 1147343, 'name': 'On or near Parking Area'}, 'longitude': '-0.605146'} context :  outcome_status : None persistent_id :  id : 79955592 location_subtype :  month : 2019-12
```

How can I create a table with correct headers for the response I get? Headers would be  'category',  'latitude', 'street', 'name', 'longitude', ' month'.

Comment: you need name of the street instead of `street` nad `name`?

Comment: Thank you. No. just a name.  The most important headers are lat/long , category, month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get dipper in dictionary tree to get some data like latitude. Results are collected into collection of lists then loaded into data frame and saved as csv file.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r=requests.get('https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=51.169,-0.633:51.186,-0.5436:51.226,-0.6224&date=2019-12')
r_json=r.json()

# collect data into list of lists
collected_data = []
for data in r_json:
    category = data.get('category')
    month = data.get('month')
    latitude = ''
    longitude = ''
    street = ''
    for key, value in data.items():
        if key == 'location':
            latitude = value.get('latitude')
            longitude = value.get('longitude')
            street = value.get('street').get('name')
    collected_data.append([category, latitude, longitude, street, month])

# load data into data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(collected_data, columns = ['Category' , 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Street', 'Month'])
# save data frame into csv
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you Zaraki. Very useful and informative. I will be able to build on your code a bit further.

Comment: @BenasPekarskis You're welcome :). You can push arrow up if this answer is useful for you.

Comment: I did, but because of my reputation on this site, it does not display publicly.